# event listener API json onchange - it is possible with JS? - how to get data from api reactivelly efficiently repeatly

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api

I have an API JSON.

this API changes very often:

- it can change 10 times in a minute
- or also 1 time an hour
- or also 1 time a month.

all things depend on the parameters passed, a few parameters passed are more likely will change.

the problem is I don't know how many times, and I don't want to fetch every millisecond.

---

so is there any way to fetch it like it is a event listener?

like something like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("APIchange", () => {
    console.log("api changed");
});
```

---

## so what do I want?

1. fetch data at the start of the app
2. wait for changes
3. if is changes don't fetch (don't consume data)

   - BUT add a button with data changed N times
4. and if someone clicks the button then fetch the data (so we don't waste internet if user don't want new data, but I want to show to him that it changed N times)

literally something like question on stackoverflow.

[image]

---

here an example of API if you want to: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?page=1&pagesize=10&fromdate=1666915200&todate=1667001600&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=javascript&site=stackoverflow (is the same of StackOverflow, mine is different but is like it)

---

yes, there is some similar answers here: [How to check if JSON is changed in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373727/how-to-check-if-json-is-changed-in-javascript) but they need everytime to fetch entire data even if not needed. I only need to add the count, create the button and increment the count, on click then fetch, button disappear

Comment: Is this your API?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes if you want is similar use it, mine is proprietary I can't show it but is literally the same concept of stackoverflow one.

Comment: here docs if you need it of StackOverflow one: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs I've pretty done all the other thing but the increment isn't that optimized if I do a setInterval of certain time.

Comment: Use websockets or server-side events

Comment: @KonradLinkowski what are web sockets? is server side using next.js? I know svelte or react. but don't know sveltekit or next.js.

Comment: [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)  and [server-side events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

Comment: You want your client to subscribe to server-side changes, correct? If it is crucial that a "trace" of changes is available, then your server must store those changes. If you just need to know roughly how many changes has occurred, then you can set up a subscription. Websocket would ideally be your medium, but you could also poll changes every n seconds with normal HTTP.