# Is this API signed request methodology secure?

Tags: node.js, api, digital-signature, hmac

I'm working on authentication for my `JSON-RPC API` and my current working strategy is using signed requests sent via `POST` over `SSL`.

I'm wondering if anyone can see any vulnerabilities that I haven't taken into consideration with the following signature method.

All communication between the client and the server is done via `POST` requests sent over `SSL`. Insecure `http` requests are denied outright by the API server.

**Dependencies**

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var moment = require('moment');
var MyAPI = require('request-json').newClient('https://api.myappdomain.com');
```

Dependency Links: [node-uuid](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-uuid), [crypto](https://www.npmjs.org/package/crypto), [moment](https://www.npmjs.org/package/moment), [request-json](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request-json)

**Vars**

```
var apiVersion = '1.0';
var publicKey = 'MY_PUBLIC_KEY_UUID';
var secretKey = 'MY_SECRET_KEY_UUID';
```

**Request Object**

```
var request = {
    requestID : uuid.v4(),
    apiVersion : apiVersion,
    nonce : uuid.v4(),
    timestamp : moment.utc( new Date() ),
    params : params
}
```

**Signature**

```
var signature = crypto.createHmac('sha512',secretKey).update(JSON.stringify(request)).digest('hex');
```

**Payload Packaging** (Sent as cleartext via `POST` over `SSL`)

```
var payload = {
    request: request,
    publicKey : publicKey,
    signature : signature
}
```

**Resultant Payload JSON Document**

```
{
  "request" : {
    "requestID" : "687de6b4-bb02-4d2c-8d3a-adeacd2d183e",
    "apiVersion" : "1.0",
    "nonce" : "eb7e4171-9e23-408a-aa2b-cd437a78af22",
    "timestamp" : "2014-05-23T01:36:52.225Z",
    "params" : {
      "class" : "User"
      "method" : "getProfile",
      "data" : {
        "id" : "SOME_USER_ID"
      }
    }
  },
  "publicKey" : "PUBLIC_KEY",
  "signature" : "7e0a06b560220c24f8eefda1fda792e428abb0057998d5925cf77563a20ec7b645dacdf96da3fc57e1918950719a7da70a042b44eb27eabc889adef95ea994d1",
}
```

**POST Request**

```
MyAPI.post('/', payload, function(response){
    /// Handle any errors ...
    /// Do something with the result ...
    /// Inspect the request you sent ...
});
```

**Server-Side**

And then on the server-side the following occurs to authenticate the request:

1. `PUBLIC_KEY` is used to lookup the `SECRET_KEY` in the DB.
2. `SECRET_KEY` is used to create an HMAC of the `request` object from the payload.
3. The `signature` hash sent in the payload is compared to the hash of the `request` object  created on the server. If they match, we move on to authenticating the `timestamp`.
4. Given that we can now trust the `timestamp` sent in the cleartext `request` object since it was included in the `signature` hash sent from the client, the `timestamp` is evaluated and the authentication is rejected if the request is too old. Otherwise, the request is authenticated.

So far as I understand, this is a secure method for signing and authentication requests sent over `SSL`. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update on JSON Property Order**

> The order of properties when using `JSON.stringify` is essentially random, which could cause signature mis-matches.

Using this signing process over the past few weeks I haven't run into any hash mis-match issues due to the order of the properties in the JSON `request` object. I believe it's because I only stringify the `request` object literal once, right before the client-side hash is calculated. Then, the `request` object is in JSON format as part of the `payload`. Once received by the server, the hash is created directly from the JSON object received in the payload, there's no second `JSON.stringify` method invoked, so the signature always matches because the order of the properties is determined once, by the client. I'll keep looking into this though as it seems like a weak point, if not a security concern.

Comment: The main flow I see is that JSON.stringify does not guarantee to give the same output for object. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8931967/1016033

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Alexey. However, the ordering of the properties within the object is not a concern. In fact, that's the whole reason for using JSON objects as the form of the payload, to obviate the need for ordered parameters in the `request` method.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. The `result` `error` `request` parameters of the callback function are a a misrepresentation in this post. I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.stringify` does not guarantee order of properties. For example, object

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
```

could be serialized in two ways: `{"a":1,"b":2}` or `{"b":2,"a":1}`. They are the same from JSON point of view but they will result it different HMACs.

Imaging, that for signings your `JSON.stringify` produced first form, but for checking signature second one. Your signature check will fail although signature was valid.

Answer (score 2):

The only fishy thing I see here would be the JSON.stringify as posted in other comments, but you can use:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stable-stringify

That way you can have a deterministic hash for you signs.